# Is this the correct way to use Google Drive API for Android?

Tags: android, credentials, google-drive-android-api

I wanted to try Google Drive API for android, specificaly AppFolder as per [Storing Application Data](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder) to store data that user generates in my application and to use that to sync between devices.

As I could gateh I need credential for this API to work (see some other SO posts about resolution intent returning RESULT_CANCELLED). So I went to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials and pressed "Create Credentials" button. I was offered drop down list with (among others) option "Help me choose". Nice, or so I thought. I picked that. On the foloowing screen I was asked a few questions:

Which API are you using? -> I chose Google Drive API
Where will you be calling the API from? -> I chose Android
What data will you be accessing? -> At that point two options are offered: User data (Access data belonging to a Google user, with their permission) and
Application data (Access data belonging to your own application).

I chose ApplicationData as I only want to save data generated with my app and not acces other user data on their Google Drive. Buuutttt... as soon I selected Application Data a popup appeared with following text:

> Application data cannot be accessed securely from Android. Please
>   consider selecting another platform.

Why? In the first link I gave it is presented that Google Drive AppFolder is a method to store app data. And here it says it is not a secure access. Do I understand something wrong or is this inconsistency on Google's side?
Or should I just ignore this warning?
What is the correct approach?

EDIT:
As it turns out you cannot even proceed with "Application Data" option so I chose "User data" and created OAuth 2.0 client ID. But still... is this the correct approach?